# How to make a Contact us functionality of website in android application?

Tags: android, android-intent

I need  "Contact Us" functionality which is generally used in website.How to send emails to mail id's provided by user. I know that using Intent we can send email. Using intent we can open default mail app in phone and able to send mail, But how to send mail without opening mail app.

Comment: so, your question is "how to send mail without opening mail app" ?

Comment: Take a look at this [discussion][1] Maybe JavaMail in cooperation with android is a workable solution for you?


  [1]: http://Take%20a%20look%20at%20this%20discussion:%20https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/nHvKChtpV6k%20Maybe%20JavaMail%20in%20cooperation%20with%20android%20is%20a%20workable%20solution%20for%20you?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it server-side: You make an HTTP-POST Request with all the data which you want to send in it.

Comment: why `GET` ? `POST` is better for longer content & less chance to be captured by network capture tool.

Comment: And now a listening user can send spam through your service :(

Answer (score 0):

Use WebView.
your "mailto:" tag will not be picked by any app as they will not have access to your webview.

Answer (score 0):

I think the user needs to open the mail app, as you can't assure from which email he wants to send you a contact message. If the user has an already configured account or not, is something you may not know. Maybe he just wants to send you info without using his email.

If you still want to create a contact us going through email, I'd go for [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8284804/616225).

Otherwise, something like what @niklas said would be ok, but maybe encrypting the content, and probably not sending it as an email, but storing it into a database (so they can just fill the database with trash, instead of exploiting your service to send spam)

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaMail API ... See this below link.

[Sending emails without user intervention](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)

Comment: How can i do without giving password?