# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am writing an app in which i am trying to send an email with some data, but whenever i do click on Submit button to send an email, *getting* : **Unfortunately App has Stopped**

**Error:**

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain (has extras) }
```

**Code:**

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
String aEmailList[] = { "myaccount@gmail.com" };  
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);   
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body.toString()));
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

**Logcat:**

```
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO typ=text/plain (has extras) }
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at app.my.BookAppointmentActivity$6.onClick(BookAppointmentActivity.java:206)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-01 08:34:22.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Testing in emulator or device?

Comment: @TheReader in Emulator

Comment: Try to test in device if possible.

Comment: The only differences I can see between your code and my (working) code is that I haven't used `Html.fromHtml(body.toString())`, rather I've specified a plain text String (try that?), and I'm also using `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email with:"));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Few months ago i was facing same problem, and i found a small solution, please try below code by replacing yours

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("plain/text");  
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"recepient@gmail.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body.toString()));
    try {
     startActivity(i);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
     Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "There are no email applications installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

If you will get **There are no email applications installed.** message, it means your work is done and i will suggest you to check it on real DEVICE, but i also don't know how to send it via EMULATOR

Comment: What if i have to send email via Emulator

Comment: To Configure an email in Emulator use this link:-  http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/06/how-to-send-email-from-android-emulator.html

Comment: thanks a lot... MR. KLAMITSURI @klamitsuri i can't accept answer twice, my bad luck, happy now :)

Answer (score 4):

The Android emulator seems to lack a configured email account. That's why your code crashes. I'd suggest catching an ActivityNotFoundException when trying to send:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
String aEmailList[] = { "myaccount@gmail.com" };  
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);   
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body.toString()));
try{    
  startActivity(emailIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
  Toast.makeText(this, "No activity found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Display an error message
}
```

You can get more information on this issue [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-email-intent/).

Especially this paragraph is interesting:

> If you are using an emulator, you’ll need to configure the email
>   client. If the email client is not configured, it will not respond to
>   the Intent we’ll be discussing. If you want to see the chooser in
>   action, you’ll need to configure a device using multiple messaging
>   applications, such as the Gmail application and the Email application.

Comment: From your LogCat, it seems you are using android.intent.action.SENDTO. That one requires you to specify recipients and subject via an url scheme, whereas android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND (as you use it in your posted code ?!) takes these parameters as extras. See this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8284804/1691231

Comment: it opens new email to use, the blank email

Comment: Which action are you using for your `Intent` ?

Comment: how to send email via Emulator

Comment: From the text above: `you’ll need to configure the email client. If the email client is not configured, it will not respond to the Intent`

Comment: i have also clicked on useful for your answer

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using Try-Catch block you can use [resolveActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#resolveActivity(android.content.pm.PackageManager)) method on your `Intent` object. If the result is non-null, then there is at least one app that can handle the intent and it's safe to call `startActivity()`. If the result is null, you should not use the intent and, if possible, you should disable the feature that issues the intent.

You can use below solution:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
String aEmailList[] = { "myaccount@gmail.com" };  
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);   
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body.toString()));

// Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "No activity found to send mail.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

I hope it helps.