# Send message body and phone number to Viber

Tags: android, android-intent, message, contacts, viber

I try to get message and phone number in my app and then send a message to that number, I want to send this message via Viber application.  I can send message with this code :

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);    
     intent.setType("text/plain"); 
     intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "test test test"); 
     intent.setpackage("com.viber.voip");
     startActivity(intent);
```

How can I send phone number to Viber?

Comment: See link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387355/how-to-start-viber-call-from-an-android-app-new-version

Comment: @RIT it is for call but i want to send message.

Comment: @mahdi can you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to send a message using Intents to Viber.

**Option A** - will not fill in sms_body unfortunately. But will open directly dialog with specific contact:

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
smsIntent.setPackage("com.viber.voip");
smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:+1001002003"));
smsIntent.putExtra("address", "+1001002003");
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "body  text");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

**Option B** - will give you an option which user should receive the message:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setPackage("com.viber.voip");
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Message body");
```

Comment: I need option A, but it not works for me. it just open viber`s main activity!

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "body  text"); 
        startActivity(smsIntent);   

phoneNumber - is to whoom you want to send the message.
```

Comment: this crashes : ActivityNotFoundException

Comment: It means the device don't have any intent to launch the current specified intent. So, please check the condition (smsIntent.resolveActivity(mPackageManager) != null) so that we can show any message to user

Comment: But viber is installed, so why use it if it can't work ?