# how to place call from viber programmatically

Tags: android, phone-call, viber

I want to place a call programmatically from my App to Viber. I know this question asked many times in SO. but as a matter of fact, none of them works now (in the newer version).

I've tried [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387355/how-to-start-viber-call-from-an-android-app-new-version). But as mentioned in the answer. the user has to go through two steps to make a call.

I  know it is possible to place a call by just one click from app. (Reference: [this play store app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.drupe.app) is successfully placing a call from their app to viber.)

Currently, i'm using this

```
  String sphone = "+xxxxxxxxxx";
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(sphone));
  Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
  intent.setClassName("com.viber.voip", "com.viber.voip.WelcomeActivity");
  intent.setData(uri);
  startActivity(intent);
```

But as I mentioned user have to go through two steps to make a call. I've tried all solutions and also read [viber docs](https://developers.viber.com/docs/) but can't find anything. If anyone aware of how to do it in the newer version would be helpful to many developers.

Comment: @RonTLV  thanks for you comment. but please have a look at my mentioned link in question. comment link you attached and my mentioned link both are asked by same user and mine is latest one by that user

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method

```
public void call(String dialNumber) {
    try{
    Intent callIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + dialNumber));
    startActivity(callIntent);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + dialNumber));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
}
```

where this was crucial: **"android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"**.
Find [source here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16450149/6503228).

Comment: thank you for your answer . but please have a look at my mentioned link in question.  source link you attach and my mentioned link both are asked by same user  and mine is latest one by that user .