# Android studio : Send email with gmail impossible

Tags: java, android, email, security, gmail

I create an application. In this application, the users can send me an email (with gmail, my user and password are write in the script).
Unfortunately, I received several emails from Google warning me that a third party knows my password or other. In fact, it was just someone trying to send me an email. So, I did not receive the email. Can you help me solve this, this part is extremely important in my application.
thank you in advance

Comment: are you trying to create an email client application ?

Comment: GMail is trying to tell you that writing your username and password in clear in your script is a bad idea. There should be plenty of tutorials out there on how to lower such security risks.

Comment: You can open email app for this, like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14342890/2058260

Comment: no, I do not create an email client application. My app allows users to make money. The emails make it possible for me to send (with a simple click of a button) a request for a payoff (the text is pre-initialized).

Comment: I know it's a bad idea, I'm aware of the risks but I'm not sure that's what's blocking the account. I do not want to open the e-mail application, sending the e-mail must be fully managed in the application. The user must not know what will be sent (to prevent users from resuming the format of the email to make a false request for gain)

Comment: Some mails could be sent but I once received a warning saying that someone is trying to access my account (it is however what I wish since the goal is to send me to myself an email), I do not know if I am understandable enough ..

Comment: I remember i had the same issue, i have to allow less secure apps.
This might help you https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I have already activated this option

Comment: Is it possible to use the account directly of the person to be able to send the mail (with gmail for example)? (knowing that everything must be in the background)