# Email Intent display wrong addresses

Tags: android, android-intent

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284706/send-email-via-gmail) I wrote this code to send an email for multiple addresses:

```
String[] addresses = {"test@gmail.com", "some@gmail.com" ,"third@gmail.com"};

    Intent someIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto", Arrays.toString(addresses), null)) //all the addresses 
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "This is a test")
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "For my app");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(someIntent, "Send email..."));
```

**It looks like this:**

[image]

As you can see in the image for some reason I am getting extra `[` for the first email address and extra `]` for the last email address (this is causing non-valid email addresses and I can`t send the email).

Why this is happening and how can I remove those extra `[` and `]`.

Comment: Presumably, the `[` and `]` are coming from `Arrays.toString()`.

Comment: Agreed with commonsware i believe that's an array string

Comment: Try out https://stackoverflow.com/a/29615037/9263083, It works for me

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments, CommonsWare solved it.
 sometimes I really do make the silliest mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as *CommonsWare* said in his comment, the extra `[` and `]` are really coming from `Arrays.toString()`.

All I had to do is remove  `[` and `]` from the string and it all worked

```
String[] addresses = {"1tamir198@gmail.com", "some@gmail.com", "third@gmail.com"};
String cleanAddresses = Arrays.toString(addresses).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""); //remove [] from addresses

    Intent someIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto", cleanAddresses, null)) //all the addresses
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "This is a test")
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "For my app");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(someIntent, "Send email..."));
```