# How to export my sqlite database to csv in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, converters

I would like to export an sqlite database to csv in android. I tried with importing with opencsv.jar but it didn't work out. Is this an issue due to ADT version 17 upgrade. Is there any other way to convert an sqlite database to csv in android. Please help me with a example. I tried this [example](http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.ie/2012/08/database-table-export-to-csv-in-android.html)

Comment: You tried that example. And the result was?

Comment: Since the issue with CSVWriter couldn't get rid off,I wasn't able to proceed further.I did import jar file properly but it stands the same..

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5403357/1483178) provides pretty good code to start from for exporting sqlite to a csv and sending it as an email attachment.

The first few columns are hardcoded with the users data so you'll have to change that with your own data but, the core of what you need is there.