# Path of PDF Viewer Library

Tags: android

I am using PDF Viewer Library to view PDF inside an Android app. I've browsed through a lot of tutorials, one of which is [Dipak's tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152956/example-of-code-to-implement-a-pdf-reader/11153601#11153601). I want to access a PDF file stored in my assets folder instead of accessing the external storage. My problem is, I can't get the "path" right. It always return file not found.

I've tried the following, still yields the same result:

- this.getAssets()
- file:///android_assets/file_name.pdf
- file:///android_asset/file_name.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get path from asset, have to right in sd or internal memory to get the path.

**For SD Card**

First Take Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

then write it in card

```
 File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "file.pdf");
  if (!f.exists()) try {

    InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.pdf");
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();


    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fos.write(buffer);
    fos.close();
  } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }

  Staring path = f.getPath();
```

Comment: `File f = new File("Directory Where you want to place " +"/file.pdf");` will return file not found. since the file hasn't been written to the directory

Comment: visit this link to learn how to write a file in SD card  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181242/write-to-a-file-in-sd-card-in-android

Comment: tried this `File f = Environment.getRootDirectory();` still file not found >_<